# Download File doesnt work

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Im trying to create a download file functionality, but it doesnt work, it gives me a error of:
"The file "/storage/app/candidates/cvs/3/1493594353.pdf" does not exist", but im just looking at the file, and is there.

Am i missing something?

Note: im using laravel 5.4

File structure:

```
storage
- app
-- candidates
---cvs
----3
-----1493594353.pdf
- public
```

Route:

```
Route::post('candidate/cv/download-cv/','CurriculumVitaeController@downloadCV');
```

Controller:

```
public function downloadCV()
    {

        $candidate = Candidate::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
        $candidateCv = CandidateCv::where('candidate_id',$candidate->id)->first();


        $path = Storage::url('app/candidates/cvs/'.$candidate->id.'/'.$candidateCv->cv);
        $headers = ['Content-Type: application/pdf'];
        $newName = 'cv-'.time().'.pdf';

        return response()->download($path, $newName, $headers);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller download method to this:

```
public function downloadCV()
{

    $candidate = Candidate::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
    $candidateCv = CandidateCv::where('candidate_id',$candidate->id)->first();


    $path = storage_path().'/app/candidates/cvs/'.$candidate->id.'/'.$candidateCv->cv;
    $headers = ['Content-Type: application/pdf'];
    $newName = 'cv-'.time().'.pdf';

    return response()->download($path, $newName, $headers);
}
```

Also, to make things more dynamic, you could assign the `Content-type` and the returned file name extension on the fly, like this:

```
public function downloadCV()
{

    $candidate = Candidate::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
    $candidateCv = CandidateCv::where('candidate_id',$candidate->id)->first();


    $path = storage_path().'/app/candidates/cvs/'.$candidate->id.'/'.$candidateCv->cv;
    $headers = ['Content-Type: '.Storage::mimeType('/app/candidates/cvs/'.$candidate->id.'/'.$candidateCv->cv)];
    $newName = 'cv-'.time().'.'.pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    return response()->download($path, $newName, $headers);
}
```

Comment: thanks crabbly, just one more question regarding content-Type, the files could be or pdf, doc or txt, how can i make the Content type headers change depending file type is being used?